# Dynamic and TrackedSymbols

Tags: dynamic

Consider

```
Column[{
  Slider[Dynamic[x]],
  Dynamic[x;RandomReal[]],
  Dynamic[RandomReal[], TrackedSymbols:>{x}]
}]
```

I expected that both dynamics would update when I move the slider, but only the first one does. `Refresh` inside the second `Dynamic` does not help.

I have the vague feeling that I have seen this before, but at the moment I have no idea why the second dynamic does not update. Can someone help me?

Comment: I think I’ve seen this before too, but am on a phone and can’t conveniently search. Basically it’s because the last Dynamic[] has no dependency on x and TrackedSymbols does not create a dependency but will restrict it. Look up DynamicExpression[] maybe

Comment: Just insert `x;` to force it to track with `TrackedSymbols`. It’s got to do with how ``Internal`TrackExpression`` or whatever that one is called operates. `TrackedSymbols` can basically only restrict is how I think about it.

Comment: `Column[{Slider[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x; RandomReal[]],Dynamic[x; RandomReal[]]}]`